# Show $\frac{-1-\beta^{2}+2\beta\sqrt{1+\beta^{2}}}{-1+\beta^{2}}\geqslant -1+\sqrt{2}$ when $\beta>1$.

Tags: limits, inequality, derivatives

I was wondering if there is a quick way to prove (or disprove) the following inequality:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{-1-\beta^{2}+2\beta\sqrt{1+\beta^{2}}}{-1+\beta^{2}}\geqslant -1+\sqrt{2},
\end{eqnarray}

where $\beta>1$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward and does not require analyzing the derivative of the expression $\frac{-1-\beta^2+2\beta\sqrt{1+\beta^2}}{-1+\beta^2}$.

Rather, we know that the inequality

$$\sqrt{1+\beta^2}\ge \beta \tag 1$$

holds for all real-valued $\beta$.  Thus, using $(1)$, we find that for $\beta >1$,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{-1-\beta^2+2\beta\sqrt{1+\beta^2}}{-1+\beta^2}&\ge \frac{-1-\beta^2+2\beta\beta}{-1+\beta^2} \tag 2\\\\
&=\frac{-1+\beta^2}{-1+\beta^2}\\\\
&=1\\\\
&>-1+\sqrt{2}
\end{align}$$

where the inequality $(2)$ tacitly relies on the restriction that $\beta >1$.